# dart:ffi for NSURLSession

Tags: ios, dart, flutter-plugin, dart-ffi

Is it possible to access `NSURLSession` and related types via FFI from dart? I would like to use this bindings with Flutter on iOS.

If yes, could that be done with `dart:ffigen` and how would I have to configure it? There are lots of samples for ffi, but I did not find accessing system frameworks.

Comment: Why are you trying to use FFI instead of just a normal plugin? You even tagged your question [flutter-plugin].

Comment: With a normal plugin I had to pipe everything through platform channels. This means implementation on the native and on the dart side. Additionally, there might be a performance overhead.

Comment: Why wouldn't this be possible? There's a whole win32 library using ffi.

Comment: That sounds great. Do you have a link? All the samples only include local headers..

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/win32

Comment: @ChristopherMoore: I did some more research. `NSUrlSesssion` belongs to Apple's foundation framework and is implemented in Objective-C. FFI supports native C APIs. Thus, I would say it is not possible to create bindings for `NSUrlSession`.

Comment: That's why you should use a normal plugin as suggested above.

Comment: @RichardHeap:  As written above, I was looking into FFI as platform channels need implementation on the native and the dart side. Additionally, there is a performance overhead, especially when transporting bigger byte arrays.

Comment: It is possible to go from Dart->ffi->C[++]->ObjectiveC but it's horribly complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Dart team just released [`cupertino_http`](https://pub.dev/packages/cupertino_http) networking package for macOS/iOS
which leverages the new Objective-C interop support to wrap Apple’s networking `NSURLSession` library.

More info: https://medium.com/dartlang/dart-2-18-f4b3101f146c